# Visualize a JSon file in a browser

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

my server stores a JSon file in a remote path.

Simply I would like to load it in a controller, then, visualize it in a partial view.

Is it possible?
Why?

I can't get back a json file from a web-service call, it's very big.

Thanks,